# PHP get_headers recursively

Tags: php, redirect, get-headers

I'm trying to implement a header response to follow recursevely headers redirects. I've implemented the following which works correctly for the first request, but if a location redirect is found in the header, the get_headers do not return any result for the redirected location. I would like to display the header for each header request.

This is what I have done.

```
function redirectURL($domain) {

$newLocation = '';  
$domain = str_replace("\r", "", $domain);

$headers=get_headers($domain);

echo "<ul class='list-group' >";

print "<li class='list-group-item'>".$domain. "</li>";
            foreach($headers as $k=>$v){
                print "<li class='list-group-item'>".$k . ": " . $v . "</li>";
                if(strstr($v, 'Location')){
                    $location = explode(":",$v);
                    $newLocation = $location[1].":".$location[2];
                }
            }
echo "</ul>";   

if($newLocation != $domainName && $newLocation != ''){
    redirectURL($newLocation);
}

unset($headers);

return true;
}
```

Any idea? I've a online implementation ... if need to see a working code.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was just bad coding. I've made it working. 
This is a working code

```
function redirectURL($domainName) {

$i=0;
$newLocation = '';
$isNew = false;
$headers = array();
$domainName = str_replace("\r", "", $domainName);

$headers=get_headers($domainName,1);



echo "<ul class='list-group' >";

print "<li class='list-group-item'><strong>".$domainName. "</strong></li>";
            foreach($headers as $k => $v){
                print "<li class='list-group-item'>".$k . ": " . $v . "</li>";

                    if($k ==  'Location'){

                        $newLocation = $v;
                        $isNew = true;
                        print "<li class='list-group-item'><strong>".$k . ": " . $v . "</strong></li>";
                    }

            }
echo "</ul>";   

unset($headers);
//limit recurse to $i < 4 to avoid overload
if($isNew){
    $i++;
    if($i<4) {redirectURL($newLocation);}

}

return true;
}
```

You can check the working script at https://www.neting.it/risorse-internet/controlla-redirect-server.html